# How to Expand the rows in a DataGridView in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a displayed datagridview running on Visual Studio 2013 by a C# Programming. The data column named `Date` hasn't fully displayed all of it's data on it.

How will I solve this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [AutosizeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: Where should I put this? Thanks!

Comment: @BrianNebres if this works just accept my answer. thanks